# Azure Push Notification Works Randomliy

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

I have mobile application which uses a backend services to register to Azure push notification. Things were working fine until 4 days ago where the most notifications are not delivered to the application.

I'm using Service Bus Queue and WebJob to send the notification and I can see things executed successfully for Android but the notifications most of the time doesn't deliver to the app and the notification State equals Enqueued and Success equals 0 and Failure equals 0

I updated Microsoft.ServiceBus to the latest version but that didn't resolve the issue.

Last thing, Apple notifications used to work successfully but now they are throwing exception "**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The supplied notification payload is invalid**"

Does anyone face similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue when pushing notifications to iOS devices via Azure's Notification Hubs. I received the same error message when calling the "SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync" method on the hub.

I made sure that I had no illegal characters in my message by replacing "\" and "'". After reading a few posts regarding issues with max limit on notifications, we decided to limit our message size to 150 characters (a magic number, we didn't do any research to find out exactly how big a push notification message is allowed to be).

I also changed how the JSON payload was created, and I'm now using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq to create a JSON object with my payload. I previously created a simple json string for the payload, something like this :

```
var apnsMessage = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":"+message+", \"sound\" : \"default\", \"badge\" : 1}}";
```

Now, my JSON object is created as so:

```
var jsonPayload = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                aps = new { alert = message.Replace("\"", "").Replace("'", "") },
                sound = "default",
                badge = 1
            });
```

and I send the notification like this:

```
await Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(jsonPayload.ToString());
```

Hope this helps you (or anyone else with the same issue) :)

**EDIT:**
Here is a simple helper for trimming/truncating strings :)

```
 private static string GetTrimmedAndTruncatedString(string source, int length)
 {
     return source.Length > length ? source.Substring(0, length) + "..." : source;
 }
```

/Isa